# MS SQL Server - convert(datetime, string, code) -> What code for dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss (24hours)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would to `CONVERT` this string `08/12/2014 16:46:12` to a `datetime` but I do not know what code to use and it is driving me crazy. I looked on many pages but do not find it

```
CONVERT(datetime,'08/12/2014 16:46:12',???)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The [CAST and CONVERT page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) contains **all** the defined formats - just pick yours! Also: your string isn't clear - is this 8th of December, or the 12th of August ??

Comment: it is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter 131 is incorrect, because it uses the Hijri calendar - 2014 becomes 2576.
Use 103 as style parameter instead:

```
convert(datetime,'08/12/2014 16:46:12',103)
```

Despite the documentation on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp it also converts the time value (tested on SQL Server 2014 and 2008 Express).

Comment: I started with 103 but it doesnt include hh:mm:SS

Comment: That is right there are no seconds. Any idea what code to use to get them?

Comment: On our SQL-S 2014 the query includes the time value (and the seconds). Added SQL-Server 2014 to my answer.
@matt Which version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: im using 2008 but more importantly @Marc what version are you using?

Comment: @Marc Just installed an SQL 2008 Express server, created a new table TestTable (Primary-key int auto-increment ID, datetime DATE) and ran my query:
INSERT INTO TestTable
VALUES (convert(datetime,'08/12/2014 16:46:12',103))
It completed successfully including the seconds. Don't know why my setup is different from yours and Marc's.

Comment: myfields is a datetime field. Might be an explanation. I wil change to date to test that out...

Answer (score 0):

```
convert(datetime,'08/12/2014 16:46:12',13)
```

OR

```
convert(datetime,'08/12/2014 16:46:12',113)
```

One Last GO :)

```
SELECT CONCAT ((convert(datetime,'08/12/2014,103)),' ',(convert(datetime,'16:46:12',114))) AS DateTime
```

Here is a list of them all http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: Yeh i noticed, 131 is the most appropriate for you :)

Comment: updated my answer, these will most likely be the closest you can come

Comment: 113 and 13 are not working unfortunately... There are slashes in my "varchar date"